# Gcm ios push notifications in background fail

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I can receive push notifications when my app is in foreground but it is not working in background.

When I send the json has this form:

```
{
"data":{"message":"test ios push notification"},
"time_to_live":604800,
"registration_ids":["key...."],
"collapse_key":"GCM Notifications",
"content_available":1,
"priority":"high"
}
```

In my application I get in foreground (nothing in background):

```
{
    aps =     {
        "content-available" = 1;
    };
    "gcm.message_id" = " whatever ";
    message = "test ios push notification";
}
```

I think that the problem is around content_available but I dont know why I send content_available and the return is content-available. Is this a normal conversion?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED!**
Me bad, I forget to enable it in target -> Capabilities section:
[image]